# Hide scrolling page content under transparent header

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have tried a number of solution's from questions with the same title, but none of them seem to quite work for me. They all cause only the content to scroll, breaking the footer placement and preventing the actual page from scrolling which I need to have the header change sizes.

I have created a fiddle with the essentials of my site here:
https://jsfiddle.net/bsummers/nstjmxy5/1/

I am hoping to find a way to not show any of the white content box scrolling behind the header. I would like it to just disappear behind the navigation bar.

Been wrestling with this for 2 days, and running out of ideas...

```js
 $(document).on("scroll",function(){
  if($(document).scrollTop()>100){ 
   $("header").removeClass("large").addClass("small");
   }
  else{
   $("header").removeClass("small").addClass("large");
   }
  });
```

```css
body {
    background: transparent url("http://www.cdldodgeball.ca/new/wp-content/themes/party/images/background2.png") no-repeat fixed center top;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

header{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}
/* Sizes for the bigger menu */
header.large{}
header.large img{
    width: 354px;
    height: 105px;
}
/* Sizes for the smaller menu */
header.small{}
header.small img{ 
    width: 250px; 
    height: auto; 
}
header, nav, header img{
  transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
  -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transition: all 1s; /* Opera */
}

nav{
  background: #444;
  line-height: 50px;
}

section.content {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 160px;
    height: 1000px;
    
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

main#content {
    background: blue;
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
aside {
    background: red;
    display: table-cell;
    min-width: 200px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 200px;
}

footer{
    background: green;  
    position: relative;
    top: 160px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="fullwidth large" role="banner">
 <div class="container">
    
<a id="logo" href="#" rel="home"><img class="logo" src="http://www.cdldodgeball.ca/cms/wp-content/themes/CDL/images/logo.png" /></a>
    
   <nav role="navigation">
    Navigation
   </nav>
  </div>  
</header>


<section class="content">
  <main role="main" id="content">
      content
    </main>
    <aside>
      sidebar
    </aside>
</section>



<footer role="contentinfo" class="fullwidth">
 <div class="container">
    FOOTER        
 </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: So essentially, you want the header bar to not be transparent?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option without changing your html structure is to add the same background image on your header and apply the `rgba()` opacity to the `.container`:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nstjmxy5/3/)

```
body {
    background: transparent url("http://www.cdldodgeball.ca/new/wp-content/themes/party/images/background2.png") no-repeat fixed center top;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

header{
    background: transparent url("http://www.cdldodgeball.ca/new/wp-content/themes/party/images/background2.png") no-repeat fixed center top;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}
.container {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

Comment: It's amazing how you can stare at something so long, and miss something so simple. Thanks this works like a charm.